# Showing that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ is open and continuous, but not closed.

Tags: general-topology

I'm stuck with this one:

> Show that $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$, with $f(x,y)=x,$ is **open** and **continuous**, but **not closed**.

Here's what I've done so far:

> $i)$ **Open**: Obviously the projection on the real axis of any open disk gives an open interval, so that's true.
>
> $ii)$ **Not closed**: We can look at the graph of $g(x)=1/x$. It's a subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$, and closed with the usual topology in there, but it's projected into an open interval on $\mathbb{R}$.

What I cannot figure out is how to prove that this projection is continuous. That is, finding that open sets in $\mathbb{R^2}$ are mapped through $f^{-1}$ to open sets.

I'd appreciate any hint.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @quasi fixed, thanks.

Comment: The projection function is just $f$ which is a polynomial, hence continuous. Applying $f$ to the points of the curve $y=1/x$ yields the domain of $g$, which is the set of all nonzero real numbers (which is not closed).

Comment: Take a basis of open sets in $\Bbb R$ and show $f^{-1} (B)$  is open in $\Bbb R^2$, for instance if you take open intervals as the basis, then necessarily you have the pre-image eqaul to  {$B, \Bbb R$}, which is open in the product topology.

Comment: @quasi: is there way to show that polynomials are continuous which doesn't rely on the fact that the projection functions are continuous?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: I guess not. But it's a question of what knowledge is considered already known.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: I missed the fact the problem specifically asks to prove that the function $f(x,y)=x$ is continuous. Thus, MPW's answer is the right way.

Comment: @quasi right.  As an instructor, MPW's solution is the one I would be looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that if $U$ is open in $\mathbb R$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.

But what is $f^{-1}(U)$? It's just $U\times \mathbb R$, which is clearly open in $\mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ (it is a basic open set in the product topology).

Comment: Maybe that's a silly question, but didn't I find an open subset mapped onto a closed subset (on the non-closeness example)? Would't that contradict the definition of continuous?

Comment: I don't see that, but it doesn't matter if an open set is mapped onto a closed set. Continuity only requires that the *preimage* $f^{-1}(U)$ of every open set $U$ is open. It doesn't matter whether or not the *image* $f(W)$ of an open set $W$ is open, or closed, or neither, or both. Note also: a closed set can also be open (this happens precisely when the set is a component of the space).

Comment: @Relure.  If $C$ is the graph of $f(x) = 1/x$ (closed), then $f(C) = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ (open), but $f^{-1}(f(C)) = (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})\times\mathbb{R}$ (still open).